# Why does Shiny checkbox column add multiple entries

Tags: r, shiny

I wish to have two checkbox columns in Shiny with an all/none button. The example below seems to work, however when I print the values of the selected boxes the values in the second column are repeated.

For example, select Idaho and Illinois in column 1 and Missouri in column 2. The result is:
`Idaho Missouri, Illinois Missouri` with Missouri repeated and not all separated by commas.

Why is this?

How do I get a vector of states separated by commas without any repeats?

R Script

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  state = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas",
            "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida",
            "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa",
            "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts",
            "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana",
            "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico",
            "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma",
            "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota",
            "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington",
            "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming")
)

ui <- fluidPage(
 
  wellPanel(
    checkboxInput('all_none', 'All/None'),
    tags$label("Choose :"),
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 4,
        checkboxGroupInput(
          inputId = "checka",
          label = NULL,
          choices = df$state[1:13]
        )
      ),
      
      column(
        width = 4,
        checkboxGroupInput(
          inputId = "checkb",
          label = NULL,
          choices = df$state[14:25]
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  textOutput("selected")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(
      session, 'checka', choices = df$state[1:13],
      selected = if (input$all_none == TRUE) df$state
    )
  })
  observe({
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(
      session, 'checkb', choices = df$state[14:25],
      selected = if (input$all_none == TRUE) df$state
    )
  })
  
  output$selected <- renderText({
    paste(input$checka, input$checkb, collapse = ", ")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: My apologies. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working correctly however, how the usage of `paste` to display the result is incorrect when the length of any of the input is more than 1.

```
library(shiny)

output$selected <- renderText({
    paste(c(input$checka, input$checkb), collapse = ", ")
  })
```

To demonstrate with an example :

```
paste('a', 'b', collapse = ',') #works as expected
#[1] "a b"

paste('a', c('b','c'), collapse = ',') #doesn't work
#[1] "a b,a c"

paste(c('a', c('b','c')), collapse = ',') #works as expected
#[1] "a,b,c"
```